# USSD Menu Browser in Java

Tags: java, ussd

I want to create a simple USSD Menu Browser Application in Java. I have integrated with
 one of the Mobile operator to get the USSD Platform. And i have successfully implemented & 
tested USSR message pushing. But not able to get started with USSN (Menu Browser) in java. So please help me how to get started with simple USSD menu browser application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modem with AT commands.

You need 3GPP TS 27.007 (search in google for latest version), command called CUSD.

Send something like this `AT+CUSD=1,AA180C3602,15` which means

- 1 - I want to read result,
- AA180C3602 - *100# (GSM 7bit)
  (http://engnick.blogspot.com/2011/09/gsm-7bit-part-of-pdu-packencoding.html),
- 15 - encoding type particular to PDU.

You'll will receive as a response like this:
`+CUSD: 0,"00390030002C003000320020044004430431002E002004210443043F043504400410041E041D0020043E043F0440043504340435043B043804420020043D043E043C04350440043000200437043000200033002C00350440002F043400210020002A0035003000320023",72`
, where

- 0 - ok,
- "..." - text in UTF-16 and
- 72 - encoding type.

If your response requires an answer (menu mode), you will see 1 instead of 0 in first parameter. Just send expected number and you'll support this session (`AT+CUSD=1,31,15` - for sending a number 1).